# Is primary key by default indexed in oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, primary-key

I have a table with a long value as primary key.

Now i think that oracle by default will create a index on it.And i dont need to
create a index explicityly.

The question is :Is primary key by default indexed by oracle in this case?

Comment: I think the answer comes from definition of PK and a bit of common sense: 1. DB should check uniquness of new inserted/updated value relatively to PK; 2. it'll be fine to do it fast. And we can use undex to satisfy both points.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a primary key (or any unique column constraint) will create an index, if there is not already one present.

This is the case for almost all databases. Otherwise the uniqueness constraint cannot be efficiently enforced.